# Square brackets with mergJSON in LiveCode - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: json, web-services, livecode

The web service I'm connecting to returns its JSON in response to a query, thus:

```
[{
"dob":"25/12/68",
"firstname":"Mary",
"lastmoddate":1368519205101,
"lastname":"Smith",
"resident_id":"712d9b726603426ca36f9c77fa644ae9",
"createddate":1368519205101
}]
```

... which I pull from the web service and store in a field called "My JSON".

As you'll notice there are square brackets at the beginning and end which I believe is valid for JSON arrays?    I have the following script in LC which at the moment just retrieves the "firstname" from my array and puts it into the tMyVar for display:

```
function JSONToArray pJSON
      local tArray,tKeys
      repeat for each line tKey in mergJSONDecode(pJSON,"tArray")
          put JSONToArray(tArray[tKey]) into tArray[tKey]
      end repeat
      return tArray
end JSONToArray

on mouseUp
    put field "My JSON" into pJSON
    put JSONToArray(pJSON) into tArray
    put tArray["firstname"] into tMyVar
    answer tMyVar
end mouseUp
```

It's odd but when I run the web service JSON through mergJSON **WITH** the square brackets the tMyVar variable is empty, but if I remove the square brackets from beginning & end the variable gets populated with the contents of "firstname" just fine.

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong please?

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: Your example is valid JSON as for example http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ confirms.

Answer (score 0):

As it's returning an object inside an array then JSONToArray will create a multi-dimensional array. Change your mouseUp handler to:

```
on mouseUp
    put field "My JSON" into pJSON
    put JSONToArray(pJSON) into tArray
    put tArray[1]["firstname"] into tMyVar
    answer tMyVar
end mouseUp
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Monte I knew it must have been something simple.  In this case, me.  ;-)