# Retrieve data from server

Tags: json, livecode

I am suppose to retrieve data from a website ( example http://intimes.eu.pn/getsurvey.php )
How should i start ? guideline please

Comment: Your question is too broad, and there aren't enough details. You linked to a json response, but are you trying to consume an API or query a database? If database, what kind? What language are you using? We need as many details as possible.

Comment: I do not think that we need to know the database type. The only thing necessary is a URL which produces a JSON answer. So the question is -- how go out from LiveCode to get an answer from an URL which is JSON and then process it in LiveCode.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to get started:

```
//PLACE THE URL FROM WHICH YOU WILL RETRIEVE DATA INTO ANY VARIABLE (tURL)
put "http://intimes.eu.pn/getsurvey.php" into tURL

// RETRIEVE DATA FROM SERVER. PLACE DATA INTO VARIABLE tDATA
put url tURL into tData

// DO SOMETHING WITH tData
```

To work with JSON within Livecode, you will have to use a library that parse JSON. Investigating this is a start. http://revonline2.runrev.com/stack/82/LibJson-1-0b

Answer (score 1):

To start I suggest to read the following chapters of the Users Guide

- 11.4 Working with URLs
- 11.5 Uploading and downloading files
- 11.6 Other Internet commands

Available on MSWindows for example under C:\Program Files\RunRev\LiveCode Community 6.1\Documentation\pdf

And you probably need
https://github.com/montegoulding/mergJSON‎

**Related**
[Square brackets with mergJSON in LiveCode - what am I doing wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607199/square-brackets-with-mergjson-in-livecode-what-am-i-doing-wrong)